# How to simulate a click on a link with javascript in it

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a page that have a link that needs to be clicked every time I visit that page. Here's the source for that link:

```
<a href="javascript:rc(-1, $('postLink'))"> <b>next-page</b> </a>
```

How do I simulate that click for the `href` with javascript?

I need this code to be executed with Greasemonkey, in this way I can set this code to be run only on that certain address.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it.  Merely call the page's function the same way the link would:

```
// Click the "next-page" link
unsafeWindow.rc(-1, $('postLink'));
```

See, also: ["Following javascript: Links"](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Generate_Click_Events#Following_javascript%3a_Links).